# use a dropdown instead of a hamburger menu in a navbar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navigation

I am new to Bootstrap.

In Bootstrap 4 I would like to use a simple standard Navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

When the Navbar collapses on smaller viewports I would like to appear it as a dropdown, not as a hamburger.

How do I replace the hamburger icon and menu functionality by a dropdown element?

If this should be difficult or impossible I could also use a simple basic Nav

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

which is replaced by a by a dropdown element on smaller viewports.

Comment: Do you want the hamburger to still show on mobile but instead toggle a dropdown menu, OR do you want the entire nav to show as a dropdown menu in place of the hamburger?

Comment: I want the entire nav to show as a dropdown menu in place of the hamburger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the display `d-lg-none` on the dropdown menu, but you'll need to have duplicate menus for each "version"...

**Option 1**

Dropdown menu in place of toggler. Use dropdown instead of mobile nav...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="dropdown d-lg-none">
        <div class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/p/xohg1kOKji

**Option 2**

Use dropdown instead of mobile nav...

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/p/y9DBBlGlZO

Comment: Thank you! However this shows directly the open dropdown list, not a dropdown button which opens the list only when the user is clicking on it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking before... "I want the entire nav to show as a dropdown menu in place of the hamburger".. so you want a button to toggle the dropdown that is will be used in place of the hamburger but not the entire menu

Comment: Anyway the concept is pretty much the same: https://www.codeply.com/p/y9DBBlGlZO

Answer (score 0):

`<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>`
 This code is for displaying icon. Since bootstrap 4 does't have icons, use fontawesome icons.
Include this in head block
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`
and replace the above line with 
 `<span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i></span>`

Comment: Thanks. This does show an angle down button instead of a hamburger button. But it does not give a real dropdown element like <div class="dropdown">